# Strange Error message when Synchronizing subscriber

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, merge-replication

We have a VB.NET windows client that uses a local install of SQL Server Express that is a subscriber to our main SQL Server.

We are moving from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2017 and the VB.NET code that synchronizes the client subscription to the publishing server is now failing with an error:

> The processing of the response message failed.

The code works fine at the moment in live using SQL Server 2012 for both the RemoteServer and the LocalServer.

I turned on the output logging for the `MergeSynchronizationAgent` and got the following, the error is towards the bottom:

```
2021-05-14 01:05:46.067 Connecting to OLE DB Subscriber at datasource: 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS', location: '', catalog: 'LocalDatabase', providerstring: '' using provider 'SQLNCLI11'
2021-05-14 01:05:46.220 OLE DB Subscriber: LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS
        DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server
        Version: 14.00.1000
        catalog name: LocalDatabase
        user name: dbo
        API conformance: 0
        SQL conformance: 0
        transaction capable: 1
        read only: F
        identifier quote char: "
        non_nullable_columns: 0
        owner usage: 15
        max table name len: 128
        max column name len: 128
        need long data len: 
        max columns in table: 1000
        max columns in index: 16
        max char literal len: 131072
        max statement len: 131072
        max row size: 131072
2021-05-14 01:05:46.222 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': select SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion') 
2021-05-14 01:05:46.223 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sp_MSreplcheck_subscribe}
2021-05-14 01:05:46.223 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': set nocount on declare @dbname sysname select @dbname = db_name() declare @collation nvarchar(255) select @collation = convert(nvarchar(255), databasepropertyex(@dbname, N'COLLATION')) select collationproperty(@collation, N'CODEPAGE') as 'CodePage', collationproperty(@collation, N'LCID') as 'LCID', collationproperty(@collation, N'COMPARISONSTYLE') as 'ComparisonStyle',cast(case when convert (int,databasepropertyex (@dbname,'comparisonstyle')) & 0x1 = 0x1 then 0 else 1 end as bit) as DB_CaseSensitive,cast(case when convert (int,serverproperty ('comparisonstyle')) & 0x1 = 0x1 then 0 else 1 end as bit) as Server_CaseSensitive set nocount off
2021-05-14 01:05:46.253 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {?=call sp_helpsubscription_properties (N'RemoteServer', N'RemoteDatabase', N'RemoteDatabaseReplication')}
2021-05-14 01:05:46.254 Distributor security mode: 1, login name: , password: ********.
2021-05-14 01:05:46.269 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MShelp_profilecache(N'DEFAULT')}
2021-05-14 01:05:46.270 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2021-05-14 01:05:46.271 The upload message to be sent to Publisher 'RemoteServer' is being generated
2021-05-14 01:05:46.271 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2021-05-14 01:05:46.272 The merge process is using Exchange ID '49FF7AA5-9E98-4D72-96FF-FB86CA8C46DA' for this web synchronization session.
2021-05-14 01:05:46.272 Connecting to OLE DB  at datasource: 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS', location: '', catalog: 'LocalDatabase', providerstring: '' using provider 'SQLNCLI11'
2021-05-14 01:05:46.275 OLE DB : LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS
        DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server
        Version: 14.00.1000
        catalog name: LocalDatabase
        user name: dbo
        API conformance: 0
        SQL conformance: 0
        transaction capable: 1
        read only: F
        identifier quote char: "
        non_nullable_columns: 0
        owner usage: 15
        max table name len: 128
        max column name len: 128
        need long data len: 
        max columns in table: 1000
        max columns in index: 16
        max char literal len: 131072
        max statement len: 131072
        max row size: 131072
2021-05-14 01:05:46.276 OLE DB  'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': set nocount on declare @dbname sysname select @dbname = db_name() declare @collation nvarchar(255) select @collation = convert(nvarchar(255), databasepropertyex(@dbname, N'COLLATION')) select collationproperty(@collation, N'CODEPAGE') as 'CodePage', collationproperty(@collation, N'LCID') as 'LCID', collationproperty(@collation, N'COMPARISONSTYLE') as 'ComparisonStyle',cast(case when convert (int,databasepropertyex (@dbname,'comparisonstyle')) & 0x1 = 0x1 then 0 else 1 end as bit) as DB_CaseSensitive,cast(case when convert (int,serverproperty ('comparisonstyle')) & 0x1 = 0x1 then 0 else 1 end as bit) as Server_CaseSensitive set nocount off
2021-05-14 01:05:46.291 OLE DB  'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': exec sp_helpmergepublication @publication = N'RemoteDatabaseReplication', @reserved = 'internal', @publisher = N'RemoteServer', @publisher_db = N'RemoteDatabase'
2021-05-14 01:05:46.293 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSgetreplicainfo(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,90)}
2021-05-14 01:05:46.293 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSgetreplicainfo(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,90)}
2021-05-14 01:05:48.449 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSsetreplicainfo (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,90,?,?,0)}
2021-05-14 01:05:48.455 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sp_MSmergeupdatelastsyncinfo (?,?,?)}
2021-05-14 01:05:48.458 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSenumreplicas90 }
2021-05-14 01:05:48.460 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSenum_metadataaction_requests(?,?,?,?)}
2021-05-14 01:05:48.461 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sp_MSgetlastsentrecgens (?)}
2021-05-14 01:05:48.463 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sp_MSgetmakegenerationapplock_90(?,?)}
2021-05-14 01:05:48.561 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSmakegeneration (?, NULL,NULL,NULL,100)}
2021-05-14 01:05:48.563 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sp_MSreleasemakegenerationapplock}
2021-05-14 01:05:48.564 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2021-05-14 01:05:48.565 No data needed to be merged.
2021-05-14 01:05:48.566 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2021-05-14 01:05:48.567 Request message generated, now making it ready for upload.
2021-05-14 01:05:48.568 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2021-05-14 01:05:48.569 Upload request size is 1348 bytes.
2021-05-14 01:06:59.343 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2021-05-14 01:06:59.355 Uploaded a total of 1 chunks.
2021-05-14 01:06:59.355 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2021-05-14 01:06:59.359 The request message was sent to 'https://WebServer:444/SQLMerge/replisapi.dll'
2021-05-14 01:06:59.402 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2021-05-14 01:06:59.403 Downloaded a total of 45 chunks.
2021-05-14 01:06:59.417 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}

**2021-05-14 01:06:59.420 The processing of the response message failed.**

2021-05-14 01:06:59.420 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sp_MSmergeupdatelastsyncinfo (?,?,?)}
2021-05-14 01:06:59.422 OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS': {call sp_MSmergeupdatelastsyncinfo (?,?,?)}
2021-05-14 01:06:59.422 Disconnecting from OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS'
2021-05-14 01:06:59.422 Disconnecting from OLE DB Subscriber 'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS'
2021-05-14 01:06:59.423 Disconnecting from OLE DB  'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS'
2021-05-14 01:06:59.423 Disconnecting from OLE DB  'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS'
```

Any thoughts on what the issue could be? Or have I missed something?

Thanks

Comment: There is not enough information to help you.

Comment: Thanks for responding Mitch. What sort of information in regards to my question would be helpful?
Sorry for lack of details, I am new here.